# I have two operating systems on two different hard drives one is fast and one is slow. Why?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10-pro

This is my system:

- Intel i7-7820x CPU 3.60Ghz
- DDR4 16GB RAM
- Geforce GTX 1080TI
- ASUS ROG RAMPAGE VI EXTREME
- **Disk 1**:  Seagate BarraCuda - 2TB, 7,200 RPM
- **Disk 2**:  Western Digital - 1TB, 7,200 RPM

I have two operating systems on two different internal hard drives. one is fast and one is slow. Why? They have the same Windows 10 pro installed.

I use one more then the other but even when I use the slow one it will get real fast and the fast one will stay the same.

Someone help me and yes the slow one takes a lot of use to get back to being fast but now it just seems real slow I do not know what to do.

Comment: If you want people to help, you need to provide details about your hardware setup: What is the make and model of hard drives being used? And how are they connected to the system? Are they external or internal?

Comment: You need to add those details to your question. I went ahead and did that. But you only provided details on one drive and it is not clear if that drive is connected internally or externally. Please edit your question to add details on the connection as well as the second drive.

Comment: Have you defragmented the slow drive? This could help. Also, have you checked S.M.A.R.T values to make sure its not failing? Lastly, depending on your load its possible the one has a bigger cache which makes a difference on your workload.

Comment: I did a S.M.A.R.T with Seagate software and it gave my HDD A TEST PASSED! There was nothing bad for it to find I did a defragment seems a little better but still slow and no the cache for disk 1 is 256MB and disk 2 the fast one is 64MB but I will see how it plays out now that i have done the defragment

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find out what is your "slow". When it is "slow", open task manager and goto the performance tab, check out which resource's utilization is high. Generally when it is slow either CPU or some Disk is at high utilization. If the disk utilization is not high, then the chance of disk problem is low. If the disk utilization is high but the disk read/write speed is not very low (e.g. at least 10KB/s+) , then maybe some process is taking up disk IO resource which is not a hardware problem. If the disk utilization is 100% but the read/write speed is very slow (e.g. 0KB/s) it may be a disk hardware problem but still may recover sometime later.

Then goto the process tab (the first tab) of task manager, click CPU/disk column header to sort from high to low to see which process is taking up most CPU/disk resource. Then the problem is on that process. **Then you can search the name of that process online or ask questions about that process**.

I guess the problem is the two system's configuration/usage history is different which run some process that take up resources on only one PC, and when that process's job is done your PC get fast.